# Can't access std::move(...) C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to use the `std::move` function in `<utility>`.  So I put an include for this at the top of my code along with all the others.  However, when I use the move function eclipse underlines it as red and it won't compile.  I know I am using c++ 11 since I can declare move constructors however, this won't work.  I am using GCC to compile and I used the -std=c++11 option.  I also put this in my linker.  Before that `#include <utility>` would not show up.  Do I need to include something else?

Here is the basic prolbem.  std::move(...) does not seem to be defined.

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;
    v1 = std::move(v2); // Function move could not be resolved.
    return 0;
}
```

Also here are the options I have set on my compiler -O3 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11

Comment: What `#include` are you adding? `std::move` is contained in `<utility>`.

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the full text of the compiler error in your question.

Comment: Did you add the `-std=c++11` to compiler parameter in the eclipse project setting? (Or secretly...just do a casting to (T&&)...

Comment: I added -std=c++11 to the GCC C++ compiler.  Before doing this I got a build error when I write move move constructor.

Comment: What is the version of GCC you are using?

Comment: Did you have build errors? Or you have only Eclipse underlined errors?

Comment: Build Errors and Eclipse Errors

Comment: can you pass -v to compiler and paste output, than somebody might help you

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK. But you should update your gcc to newest version. Gcc 4.7.2 don't have everything implemented from c++11 standard.

Comment: The program [compiles with GCC 4.7.2, with the options specifed](https://godbolt.org/z/L5q3Mi). I.e, the
problem is non-reproducible. When question was asked in November 2013, GCC 4.7.3 was the
latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure is not defined? Perhaps your error is at linking time cause the linker cannot find the library?

Whether the case, you have to add library paths to your eclipse project settings as well as include paths.

I've compiled your example and after executing ldd on the generated binary I can see there are linking dependences, I hope this help:

[image]